# Angular v6: How to disable particular formControl of formArray based on the selection value?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have checked many Stackblitz examples for formArray validations and disabled formControl based on the other formControl value and tried with the same approach but in my form it is not applying the same thing.

Validation on the `qty` formControl is not working and if user select a value active from selection then fromControl `qty` should be enabled otherwise it should be disabled by default that is also not working properly.

What the thing i am missing ?

Here is my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdbfyg) demo.

Reference which i have used for validation. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validate-dynamic-formarray-formbuilder-pru78n?file=app/app.component.ts

HTML component

```
<div formArrayName="dataCollection">
    <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let element of data; let first = first; let i = index">
        <div *ngIf="!first">----------</div>
        <div formArrayName="sizes">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="j" *ngFor="let qtys of data[0].sizes; let j = index">
                <div class="col">
                    <mat-form-field class="">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="qty">
              <!-- <p *ngIf="element['controls'].qty?.errors?.required">Qty is required</p>
              <p *ngIf="element['controls'].qty?.errors?.pattern">Error pattern</p> -->
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="">
            <mat-select placeholder="Status"
              formControlName="statusMethod"
              (selectionChange)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
              <mat-option value="AC">Active</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="IN">Deactive</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS Component

```js
onSelectionChanged({value}) {
  if (value === 'IN') {
    this.dataForm.get('dataCollection').get('qty').disable();
  } else {
    this.dataForm.get('dataCollection').get('qty').enable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onSelctionChanged()` method there are no references to the selected FormArray indices. You must pass them from the template like `(selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged(i, j)"`.
Now you can use the indices to access your data in the nested FormArrays:

```
onSelectionChanged(i, j) {
  const control = (<FormArray>((<FormArray>this.dataForm.get("dataCollection")).at(i).get("sizes"))).at(j);
  if (control.get("statusMethod").value === "IN") {
    control.get("qty").disable();
  } else {
    control.get("qty").enable();
  }
}
```

Further information about accessing data in FormArray can be found in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) or in this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647073/angular-2-accessing-data-from-formarray).

Here is the updated version of your [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3kxxe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: On page load it is still active and also validation for `qty` formControl is not working.

Comment: The 'onSelectionChanged()` method only takes effect if you change something. If you want to have this functionality when the page is loaded, you need a loop which, after the form is filled with data, passes through all FormArray elements. In your case a nested loop. The requirements for the validation are not clear to me.

Comment: Validation should be like it will be entered only number, and i have set that into formControl but into HTML it is not going to set.

Comment: I have updated the [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydxgdn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with an initial toggle method called `toggleFields()`.
I think the validation works well. If you enter 3 numbers and save, the field is valid... otherwise not. If you want to allow only numbers on the html side, then you have to make the input field of `type="number"` like `<input matInput type="number" formControlName="qty">`.