# How can I update value of child formcontrol in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have one formcontrol like event and event in 2 more form control like city and state. So how can I update value of city and state ( There are multiple city and state )
my form group example:

In starting I declared event form control

```
this.dataform = this.fb.group({ event: new FormArray([]) });
```

then dynamically I add city and state form control

```
const field: FormArray = (this.dataform.get('event') as FormArray);
field.push(
      new FormGroup({
        city: new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required
        ]),
        state: new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required
        ])
      })
    );
```

So how can I update value of city and state formcontrol

event:[
{
"city": "",
"state": ""
},
{
"city": "",
"state": ""
}
]

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. In which item do you want to change the value? I mean, how do you find the item in `event` to change the value? How do you use `event` in the form controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick Search leads i.e. to [Angular 2: Accessing data from FormArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647073/angular-2-accessing-data-from-formarray)

So you can use something like this where '1' is the index:

```
form.get('event.1').patchValue(...)
or
form.controls.list.at(1).patchValue(...)
or
form.get('event').at(1).patchValue(...)
```

Havent tried the latter but basically its about getting the control that you want to update and then setting it. Since its a FormArray, you need to access it by the index.